# angularjs ng-repeat and dropdown ng-change with multiple rows issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need some directions to the problem I am facing.
Scene: I have a table that has 5 columns (Publication Name, Type ...etc). This table can be dynamically created. The columns have dropdown boxes (HTML select tag). All columns are populated dynamically from the database. The first column "Publication Name" has some data with few names and respective id `{id, name}`. Based on the selection, I get the values for the rest of the columns from the database. For eg. I selected x from the first column, the second column value is 5, and so on. I want to assign the value 5 to the second column says "Type" column of the fourth row. Since it is dynamically created, the model name of the control remains the same and it is not recognizing the 4th row "Type" dropdown box.

**Html Table below**

| Publication Name | Publication Type | Another Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dropdownbox1 | Dropdownbox2 | Dropdownbox3 |
| Dropdownbox1 | Dropdownbox2 | Dropdownbox3 |

Now, when I select Dropdownbox1 of the second row, I need to change the value of Dropdownbox2 of the second row. Since I am using ng-repeat, the ng-model name remains the same. I am not using $index because I am tracking the values by their respective IDs.  The ng-model name of the second column is compPub.pub_type_id; comPub being an instance which is used in ng=repeat as data-ng-repeat="compPub in NewCompPub. SingleNewPub". Accessing the ng-model name as compPub.pub_type_id is not recognized. So, I am unable to set the value.

**The HTML select code is**

```
<pre>
 <select class="form-control" id="typeId" data-ng-model="compPub.pub_type_id" data-ng-options="pub.name for pub in pubTypes track by pub.id"><br/>
  <option value="" selected disabled>--Nothing Selected--</option><br/>
</select><br/>
</pre>
<br/>
data-ng-model="compPub.pub_type_id"<br/>
data-ng-options="pub.name for pub in pubTypes track by pub.id"<br/>

I am calling this angularjs function in the controller.js file 

$scope.getSelectedPubNameDefault = function (id) {<br/>
            alert(id);<br/>
            var serviceCall = damamService.getPubNameDefaults(id);<br/>            
            serviceCall.then(function (data) {<br/>
               // console.log(data.data.Table);<br/>
                var tid = data.data.Table[0].pub_type_id;<br/>
                alert(tid);<br/>
                // $scope.NewCompPub.SingleNewPub[index].pub_type_id = { "pub.id": data.data.Table[0].pub_type_id };<br/>
                //document.getElementById('typeId').selectedIndex = tid;<br/>
                $scope.compPub.pub_type_id.id = { 'id': tid };
            });<br/>
        }; <br/>
```

This is my first query on StackOverflow, although I have used this forum extensively and got solutions to many of the problems. Please excuse me if there is something that I have not followed while posting the question. Sorry, the question appears lengthy but I had to explain clearly to get a solution. Thanks.

Comment: where is this `getSelectedPubNameDefault() ` called?

Comment: In the data-ng-change="getSelectedPubNameDefault()" of all the first-column dropdown boxes.

Comment: you could pass `$index` or `compPub` and use them to change the rows

Comment: You can pass the whole object from the ng-repeat into the ng-change function

Comment: Will try these suggestions and revert. Sorry, I didn't check this early!

Comment: Passed the $index with the function and used JQuery to update the dropdownboxes. It is working now. $('#typeId' + index).val(tid); Thanks for the suggestion. 

However, it landed with another issue. While saving the data to the DB using the API, the $scope values are not updated but remains as null. On searching google and stackoverflow for solutions, I found some suggesting to do a $scope.apply(), which didn't work. Some suggested to use $('#typeid').trigger('input'); and                 $('#typeid').trigger('change'); This didn't work too. Any other suggestions?